# Zopim Chat Api Integration issue

Tags: javascript, php, zopim

I am trying to integrate Zopim chat API. But previously I'm already using custombox API. Html code for Zopim chat and custombox appears on same place of DOMtree i.e after body tag. The issue is when I close custombox, its removes zopim chat html also. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.